# iAd layout in iPad landscape mode

Tags: ipad, landscape, iad, portrait

I have a problem:

I've added an iAd Banner into my Universal Application.
But if I want to size the iAd Banner on the iPad so, that it is as big as the width of the iPad Portrait Mode, it works, but on the Landscape mode it's still as big as the width of the Portrait mode.
But I want that the Banner is as big as the iPad **Landscape** mode on the landscape mode.
Is that possible?
I hope you could understand me.

Best Regards & Thanks

Comment: Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out!
First I've set the View Layout to Landscape mode.
Then I've changed the width of the iAd Banner as wide as the width of the Landscape mode.
After that I've promoted two User Constraints of the iAd Banner:
Leading Space to Superview
Trailing Space to Superview

And that's it. Test the app on the iPhone Simulator.